# Печать нескольких изображений за один раз

Tags: c#, print

Отправляю на печать n-картинок. Все происходит медленно. Как сказать принтеру, чтобы он печатал файлы как один документы. Вариант перевода в PDF не подходит.

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Printer Name";
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true; //or false!
pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
{
    Image i = Image.FromFile(@"C:\...\...\image.jpg");
    Rectangle m = args.MarginBounds;

    if ((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
    {
        m.Height = (int)((double)i.Height / (double)i.Width * (double)m.Width);
    }
    else
    {
        m.Width = (int)((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height * (double)m.Height);
    }
    args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, m);
};
pd.Print();
```

Comment: PrintPage будет вызываться в цикле, если в конце его поставить в вашем случае args.HasMorePages = true; И соответственно определять программно когда все страницы отпечатаются и тогда установить args.HasMorePages = false;